# I hate Valentine's Day

Tags: riddle, word

I played her my favorite song on my favorite [prefix]

As I gave her a decorated Hallmark [infix]

And said, "I hope I'm [suffix] to make you happy"

But alas, she said no, and left me alone.

Is my heart just [whole word] to you?

Comment: Idk, wouldn't this have been better with more freedom than just single words?

Comment: You should have played **her** favourite song instead :)

Comment: @DonThousand I don't get it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I played her my favorite song on my favorite [prefix]

> disc

As I gave her a decorated Hallmark [infix]

> card

And said, "I hope I'm [suffix] to make you happy"

> able

But alas, she said no, and left me alone.

Is my heart just [whole word] to you?

> discardable